# Rails lightweight authorization solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, roles, cancan

I have a rails app where users can buy and sell products. I have implemented the authentication system from devise.

But now I want to have two different types of users (sellers, buyers). At the time of signup, users can choose what role they want.

I had seen many tutorials but none of them was helpful.

Should I use CanCanCan?
Is there a simpler alternative?

Answer (score 1):

[CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) was a very popular gem for authorization developed by Ryan Bates but it's not maintained anymore. The community-based [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) project maintains an updated version of CanCan.

The [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) gem is gaining a lot of popularity for Rails authorization lately and it's very well maintained. So, it's preferred these days.

There is another one [authority](https://github.com/nathanl/authority)

While `cancan` and `pundit` are the most popular choices for production grade Rails applications, if you want something really **lightweight**,
[action_access](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/action_access) is the way to go and its work very well with Rails 4.

Comment: thanks sir for your help but i just want to know how to make roles in a rails app actually am really new to all this stuff and am trying to teach my self....i just want to know how to implement roles system in my app